# SPARQL query on handmade Ontology .owl

Tags: sparql, owl, ontology

I'm trying to make a SPARQL query out of an ontology that I've modeled, but I'm having trouble in determine which prefixes I should use. For example, how to return all individuals (owl:NamedIndividuals) from this ontology, from the class Pub, with all subClasses data (Tags, Description, CID, etc)?

For such queries I'm using Protégé 'SPARQL Query' plugin

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT ?s ?o ?p
    WHERE { ?s rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual .
            FILTER ( ?s = 'Philosophy' )
          }
```

Ontology:
https://ipfs.io/ipfs/QmYdBz4hTwhStf5eR7fv6imoKny82Y9QbyqNoZAbjceXiu

edit. sharing a partial solution for this question

```
SELECT ?subject ?description ?date ?tags
WHERE {

    #?subject <http://127.0.0.1:8000/gott2.owl#has_CID> <http://127.0.0.1:8000/gott2.owl#QmWCpZXGECFmwyoySt86LkJduE275iMffsNu6dFZ8q23h4>.
  
  OPTIONAL {?subject <http://127.0.0.1:8000/gott2.owl#has_CID> ?object.}
  OPTIONAL {?subject  <http://127.0.0.1:8000/gott2.owl#has_description> ?description.}
  OPTIONAL {?subject  <http://127.0.0.1:8000/gott2.owl#has_tags> ?tags.}
  OPTIONAL {?subject  <http://127.0.0.1:8000/gott2.owl#has_date> ?date.}
  
  BIND (STR(?subject) AS ?s) .
  BIND (STR(?tags) AS ?t) .

  OPTIONAL { FILTER CONTAINS ( LCASE(?s) , ENCODE_FOR_URI("philosophy"))} .
  OPTIONAL { FILTER CONTAINS ( LCASE(?t) , ENCODE_FOR_URI("philosophy"))} .
}
```

Comment: Very nice placing your ontology at that link.

Comment: You have some loopback addresses in your ontology.  They may make answering your question difficult.

Comment: Try something like:
SELECT ?subject WHERE {?subject rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual . ?subject ?predicate "Philosophy"}

Comment: the filter `FILTER ( ?subject = 'Philosophy' )` will never gonna work because a string literal is never the subject of an RDF triple and SPARQL is nothing more than a query language for RDF. You have to use the URI of the individual or just omit the filter to get all individuals. Clearly, your query isn't close to what you want. Like, all individuals of the class `Pub` needs a query like `SELECT * WHERE {?s a <YOUR_PUB_CLASS_URI_HERE>}` - and again use the URI

Comment: @UninformedUser indeed, the next step debugging it was thinking of the type of data I was dealing with, if it was a string or what, and plenty of URIs were all around. Gonna edit/update the solution I've found.